# Why is my isColliding function not working?

Tags: python, python-turtle

When my turtle moves forward, it should check if it is within the desired area, but it isn't working.

I tried checking the specific coordinates of the box, but that did not work.
In the isColliding function, it should just be checking if my turtle is within the topLeft x and bottomRight x and within the topLeft y and bottomLeft y. Then it should be returning a true or false, but when I print the expression to check it's only returning a false.

Not sure if it matters, but I am using PyCharm Community Edition

```
import turtle as t

colors = ["orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple"]

drawturt = t.Turtle()
drawturt.shape("turtle")

obs = t.Turtle()

allObs = {
    "testBox": {
        "topLeft": (100, 100),
        "bottomRight": (150, 50),
        "color": "purple",
        "objectType": "square"
    }
}

def isColliding(object_name):
    return float(
        allObs[object_name]["topLeft"][0]) < drawturt.xcor() < float(
        allObs[object_name]["bottomRight"][0]) and float(
        allObs[object_name]["topLeft"][1]) < drawturt.ycor() < float(
        allObs[object_name]["bottomRight"][1])

def drawObj(object_name):
    print(f"drawing {object_name}")
    print("Color: " + allObs[object_name]["color"])
    print("Top Left Corner: " + str(allObs[object_name]["topLeft"]))
    print("Bottom Right Corner: " + str(allObs[object_name]["bottomRight"]))
    obs.penup()
    obs.ht()
    obs.speed(0)
    obs.color(allObs[object_name]["color"])
    obs.goto(allObs[object_name]["topLeft"])
    obs.pendown()
    obs.begin_fill()

    obs.goto((float(allObs[object_name]["bottomRight"][0]), float(allObs[object_name]["topLeft"][1])))
    obs.goto(allObs[object_name]["bottomRight"])
    obs.goto((float(allObs[object_name]["topLeft"][0]), float(allObs[object_name]["bottomRight"][1])))
    obs.goto(allObs[object_name]["topLeft"])

    obs.end_fill()

def move_forward():
    drawturt.forward(5)
    if isColliding("testBox"):
        drawturt.color("red")
    else:
        drawturt.color("black")

def turn_right():
    drawturt.right(5)

def turn_left():
    drawturt.left(5)

def move_backward():
    drawturt.backward(10)

def clear():
    drawturt.clear()
    drawturt.ht()
    drawturt.penup()
    drawturt.goto(0, 0)
    drawturt.setheading(0)
    drawturt.st()
    drawturt.pendown()

for targetObject in allObs:
    if allObs[targetObject]["objectType"] == "square":
        drawObj(targetObject)

t.onkeypress(move_forward, "w")
t.onkeypress(turn_right, "d")
t.onkeypress(turn_left, "a")
t.onkeypress(move_backward, "s")
t.onkey(clear, "r")

t.listen()

t.done()
```

Comment: what you mean by "isn't working". What result are you getting and what would be the expected result?  Your `isColliding` function returns a float instead of a boolean. Why are you returning a float? And where are you calling the `isColliding` function to check for collisions?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your primary issue is that you have the Y comparison in `isColliding` backward.  Your secondary issue is you're doing unnecessary type coercions.  My rework of your code that I believe works as you describe:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

allObs = {
    "testBox": {
        "topLeft": (100, 100),
        "bottomRight": (150, 50),
        "color": "purple",
        "objectType": "square"
    }
}

def isColliding(object_name):
    x, y = drawturt.position()
    targetObject = allObs[object_name]

    return targetObject["topLeft"][0] < x < targetObject["bottomRight"][0] and targetObject["topLeft"][1] > y > targetObject["bottomRight"][1]

def drawObj(object_name):
    targetObject = allObs[object_name]

    print(f"drawing {object_name}")
    print("Color:", targetObject["color"])
    print("Top Left Corner:", targetObject["topLeft"])
    print("Bottom Right Corner:", targetObject["bottomRight"])

    obs.penup()
    obs.hideturtle()
    obs.speed('fastest')
    obs.color(targetObject["color"])
    obs.goto(targetObject["topLeft"])
    obs.pendown()

    obs.begin_fill()

    obs.goto(targetObject["bottomRight"][0], targetObject["topLeft"][1])
    obs.goto(targetObject["bottomRight"])
    obs.goto(targetObject["topLeft"][0], targetObject["bottomRight"][1])
    obs.goto(targetObject["topLeft"])

    obs.end_fill()

def move_forward():
    drawturt.forward(5)

    if isColliding("testBox"):
        drawturt.color("red")
    else:
        drawturt.color("black")

def turn_right():
    drawturt.right(5)

def turn_left():
    drawturt.left(5)

def move_backward():
    drawturt.backward(5)

def clear():
    drawturt.hideturtle()
    drawturt.clear()
    drawturt.penup()
    drawturt.home()
    drawturt.pendown()
    drawturt.showturtle()

screen = Screen()

drawturt = Turtle()
drawturt.shape("turtle")

obs = Turtle()

for targetObjectName in allObs:
    if allObs[targetObjectName]["objectType"] == "square":
        drawObj(targetObjectName)

screen.onkeypress(move_forward, "w")
screen.onkeypress(turn_right, "d")
screen.onkeypress(turn_left, "a")
screen.onkeypress(move_backward, "s")
screen.onkey(clear, "r")

screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```